# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I read some tutorial and knew how to create basic relationships. But I can't apply to my case.

I have 2 model look like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :created_user, :updated_user
    has_many :reports
end
```

and

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :title, :updated_user 
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I can write:

```
report.user
```

But I want write somethings more

```
report.updated_user // instead of User.find(report[:updated_user]) 
user.created_user // instead of User.find(user[:created_user])
user.updated_user // instead of User.find(user[:updated_user])
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Report model to this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :title, :updated_user 
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
    belongs_to :updated_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'updated_user'
end
```

Comment: make sure to add these foreign keys in migration files, after that refresh DB

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, does this way run faster than I use User.find(report[:updated_user]) ?

Comment: It probably doesn't make a huge difference, but it's definitely cleaner syntax this way!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
@report=report.find(id)
@report.user.updated_user
```